# how to find out all the PID of Apache httpd processes that are in reading state?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, httpd

The Apache web server in my RHEL shows many requests in R (..reading..) state. I want to find the client IPs that are making Apache wait in reading state. Specifically: I want to find out all the client IPs that are **spending too long to send the request**.

The [server-status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html) module is not enough. Server status does not show the client information when the PID is in reading state.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `netstat` program with the `-l` flag to get a list of listening process. You probably want to run it with `sudo` so that you can use the `-p` flag to get process PIDs. You might also want the `-t` flag to only show tcp sockets instead of tcp and udp. Sometimes the `-n` flag is nice to show only port numbers and IPs without resolving them to services and names.

After that it's a matter of greping for just your apache process and then extracting the PID from the output columns:

```
sudo netstat -lntp | grep httpd | awk -F '[/ ]*' '{print $7}'
```

Answer (score 1):

To find out the details about connections which are spending more than 15 seconds in HTTP request reading phase, I wrote this command:

```
links http://localhost/server-status | tee | grep "..reading.." | awk '{if ($6>15) print "lsof -a -n -i TCP -p"$2}' | sh |  grep -E "TCP.*(ESTABLISHED)"
```

Comment: What does `links` do?  What distro are you using where that's available?

Comment: its a command line web browser

Comment: This requires Apache module mod_status to be enabled as described here: https://serverfault.com/questions/350559/find-what-php-script-is-running-on-each-httpd-process