# Apache httpd process using too much memory

Tags: apache-2.2, memory, httpd, prefork

I am running a dedicated apache web server on CentOS6 it has:
12GB memory
4 cpus

My httpd config is as follows, from /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
Timeout 60
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15
```

The server is using the Prefork MPM with the following settings.

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      50
MaxClients       50
MaxRequestsPerChild  300
</IfModule>
```

This was adjusted from a previous setting of:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
```

**THE PROBLEM**

After changing these values a few times and restarting httpd, the same thing always happens.  ONE of the PIDs goes up to 11GB memory, so I kill it manually and the memory gets freed.

Here's my free -m output after killing a rogue PID and restarting:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         11891       1132      10759          0         34        417
-/+ buffers/cache:        679      11212
Swap:         3827        227       3600
```

It looks like my httpd PIDs are taking too much memory.

```
top - 11:26:58 up  1:20,  1 user,  load average: 2.87, 2.43, 4.25
Tasks: 174 total,  12 running, 162 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 83.3%us,  4.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 10.4%id,  1.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  12177272k total,  4746532k used,  7430740k free,    50012k buffers
Swap:  3919840k total,   227860k used,  3691980k free,   776180k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 3848 apache    20   0  653m 216m 8908 R 31.3  1.8   0:11.77 httpd
 3862 apache    20   0  627m 194m 6824 R 30.3  1.6   0:09.62 httpd
 3846 apache    20   0  562m 126m 8728 R 28.6  1.1   0:10.20 httpd
 3844 apache    20   0  638m 204m 6704 R 27.9  1.7   0:08.40 httpd
 3911 apache    20   0  638m 203m 5880 R 27.6  1.7   0:04.92 httpd
 3880 apache    20   0  639m 205m 6724 R 27.3  1.7   0:06.76 httpd
 3918 apache    20   0  680m 246m 5820 S 25.3  2.1   0:05.38 httpd
 3921 apache    20   0  630m 197m 4440 R 24.0  1.7   0:01.63 httpd
 3843 apache    20   0  624m 191m 6684 R 23.3  1.6   0:07.50 httpd
 2317 mysql     20   0 2463m 116m 3584 S 23.0  1.0  20:07.12 mysqld
 3907 apache    20   0  620m 187m 5856 R 23.0  1.6   0:04.35 httpd
 3927 apache    20   0  623m 188m 3624 R 22.6  1.6   0:00.68 httpd
 3906 apache    20   0  628m 195m 6080 R 20.6  1.6   0:04.27 httpd
 3908 apache    20   0  556m 123m 5880 S  8.0  1.0   0:02.79 httpd
 3917 apache    20   0  536m 104m 6064 S  2.7  0.9   0:00.39 httpd
 3909 apache    20   0  554m 121m 6120 S  2.3  1.0   0:01.19 httpd
 3915 apache    20   0  614m 182m 6372 S  2.3  1.5   0:02.51 httpd
 3849 apache    20   0  576m 144m 6700 S  1.7  1.2   0:06.54 httpd
 3838 root      20   0  508m  84m  12m S  0.3  0.7   0:00.27 httpd
 3931 apache    20   0  509m  76m 4216 S  0.3  0.6   0:00.01 httpd
```

And then one of them always flips out and uses up ALL the memory.

```
 4076 apache    20   0 7834m 7.2g 6172 S 11.6 62.2   0:34.86 httpd
```

**MYSQL Memory**

```
[root@xxx ~]# ps aux | grep 'mysql' | awk '{print $6}'
4
148316
884
```

**APACHE Process size**

```
[root@xxx ~]#  ps aux | grep 'httpd' | awk '{print $6}'
93640
73196
133840
204352
170620
202056
120312
123600
123492
119048
131316
119744
200304
203160
118468
189300
203196
200024
124184
880
```

NETSTAT at peak (when rogue PID has eaten all of memory)

```
[root@xxx ~]# netstat -plan | grep :80
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      4235/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:74.208.104.107:80    ::ffff:208.167.230.35:47089 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:74.208.104.107:80    ::ffff:208.167.230.35:59089 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:74.208.104.107:80    ::ffff:208.167.230.35:35831 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:74.208.104.107:80    ::ffff:208.167.230.35:42075 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:74.208.104.107:80    ::ffff:208.167.230.35:49612 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:74.208.104.107:80    ::ffff:208.167.230.35:43970 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:74.208.104.107:80    ::ffff:173.199.114.19:44220 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:74.208.104.107:80    ::ffff:208.167.230.35:34405 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:74.208.104.107:80    ::ffff:208.167.230.35:33963 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:74.208.104.107:80    ::ffff:66.249.75.222:42306  ESTABLISHED 4241/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:74.208.104.107:80    ::ffff:173.199.115.67:53145 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:74.208.104.107:80    ::ffff:91.232.96.34:64675   TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:74.208.104.107:80    ::ffff:107.20.53.252:40552  ESTABLISHED 4247/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:74.208.104.107:80    ::ffff:173.199.114.19:46658 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:74.208.104.107:80    ::ffff:208.167.230.35:46954 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:74.208.104.107:80    ::ffff:74.208.104.107:33988 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:74.208.104.107:80    ::ffff:208.167.230.35:51501 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:74.208.104.107:80    ::ffff:208.167.230.35:52628 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:74.208.104.107:80    ::ffff:74.208.104.107:33989 TIME_WAIT   -
```

The server has a few different purposes, it:
Runs a bunch of Wordpress sites.
CRON jobs for different automated tasks (I killed most of these and the problem still happens)
Has mobile applications connecting to it via POST.

**QUESTIONS:**

```
1) What ELSE can I do to troubleshoot this problem?
2) How do I find WHICH PHP script might be running to take up all the memory?  Perhaps this might be some runaway script that I haven't isolated.
3) Am I editing the right file for my httpd config, /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf?
4) What are the optimal settings for my server?
5) Could there be some kind of attack or rootkit thing happening?
```

**EDIT**

I have imposed 2 permanent ulimit limits using /etc/security/limits.conf for maxlock and as (virtual memory) to 1048576KB (1GB).  This seems to have stopped the behavior, but I believe it is only a stopgap measure.  I still need some answers.

Rick

Answer (score 2):

*Noted the question is still unanswered since 2013, hopefully this got resolved now*

1. Your web server is probably under attack, e.g. XML-RPC attacks, which has a lot of traffic going through your sever non-stop. Check the `access.log` to find out the file access pattern.
2. To know which PHP is consuming most resources, following instructions in this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/350566/35989).
3. Yes.
4. Depends how does your PHP work, focus on concurrent users or computation power?
5. Same as #1. Check access log & enable application firewall if needed.

Hope it helps.